# Why is the width ignored for my custom formatter implementation?

Tags: rust, formatting

When I have an enum with `Display` implemented and I try to print it formatted, the width I give it is ignored.

```rust
use std::fmt;
enum TestEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

impl fmt::Display for TestEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            TestEnum::A => write!(f, "A"),
            TestEnum::B => write!(f, "B"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("-{value:>width$}-", value = TestEnum::A, width = 3);
}
```

I expect it to output `-  A-`, but it outputs `-A-`.

If I replace the value with the actual string instead of the enum, it does the right thing,

```rust
println!("-{value:>width$}-", value = "A", width = 3);
```

outputs

```
-  A-
```

Why is the width being ignored? What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 9):

By using `write!` in your `fmt` implementation, you are overriding the format provided by its caller.

Instead you should call `fmt` on the strings themselves:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for TestEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            TestEnum::A => "A".fmt(f),
            TestEnum::B => "B".fmt(f),
        }
    }
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d867cee38bc26ae1a82d960d59dd91b))

This will correctly print `-  A-`.